# The difference between "Multi-Threaded Programming for win32" and "Multi-Threaded Programming with C++11"

Tags: c++, multithreading

i am a rookie in C++ programming. I have a stupid question.

If I want to program multi_threading , when do I use the "Multi-Threaded Programming with C++11" and when "Multi-Threaded Programming for win32"?

In win32 uses man `CreateThread()`, In c++11 uses man `std::thread`

Comment: Pick one - two implementations doing the same, different ways (I would suggest using std::thread)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are programming under windows you can use both. If you want your program be portable on other platforms then you'll better stick to c++11.

As a general rule I would suggest you to go for c++11 if you are learning, since it's a set more coherent with c++ language. Win32 threading APIs are a C-style set of functions, not a C++ library.

On the other hand there may be valid reasons to use win32 programming, but this are buried into platform specific aspects that you probably do not need (now).

Comment: Thank you for the reply. can you give me a example for the platform specific aspects?

Answer (score 0):

Before C++11 there was no way in the standard library to create threads. CreateThread() is a Windows API function and therefore will only work on Windows.

If your compiler supports C++11 and specifically C++11 threads, you are generally better off using std::thread because it will work on with any compiler/OS that supports C++11 threads. It's worth noting that C++11 threads are basically taken from Boost threads, so if you ever run into a situation where they aren't supported, you can probably download the boost libraries and change all your std::thread calls to boost::thread and it should still work.